# How to do parameter tuning in LogisticRegression using StratifiedKFold in Python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I need to feed for example 6 C values and see the mean roc_auc_score for each 10 fold for each value of C

My attempt so far:

```py
lr = LogisticRegression(C = 1,
                          penalty='l1', 
                          solver='liblinear',  
                          tol=0.0001, 
                          max_iter=3000, 
                          intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                          multi_class='auto', 
                          random_state=42)


C = [0.01,0.05,0.1,1,10,12]

final_scores = []
mean_scores = {}
# Stratified KFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

for c in C:
    for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y)):
        print("Fold:" , fold +1)
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
        predictions = lr.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
        final_score.append(roc_auc_score(y_train, predictions))
        print("AUC SCORE:" + str(roc_auc_score(y_train, predictions)))
        mean_scores[c] = np.mean(final_scores)
        print("---")

print(mean_scores)
```

I need a resulting dictionary that as keys have c values and values have the mean of 10 fold for each c.

Edit:

```py
roc_dict = dict()

C = [0.01,0.05,0.1,1,10,12]
for c in C:
    final_scores = []
    mean_scores = {}
    for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y)):
        print("Fold:" , fold +1)
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        lr.fit(X_train,y_train)
        predictions = lr.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
        final_scores.append(roc_auc_score(y_train, predictions))
        print("AUC SCORE:" + str(roc_auc_score(y_train, predictions)))
    roc_dict[c] = np.mean(final_scores)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You can define an empty `dict` before your loop:

```py
roc_dict = dict()
```

Run your loop, but place your `list` and `dict` inside so it resets every iteration (or make new ones):

```py
for c in C:
    final_scores = []
    mean_scores = {}
    # no change here, paste your original code
    roc_dict[c] = final_scores # add this
```

It will result in this:

```py
Out[90]: 
{0.01: [0.7194940476190477,
  0.7681686046511628,
  0.653343023255814,
  0.6596194503171249],
 0.05: [0.7194940476190477,
  0.7681686046511628,
  0.653343023255814,
  0.6596194503171249],
 0.1: [0.7194940476190477,
  0.7681686046511628,
  0.653343023255814,
  0.6596194503171249], # ... etc. But with 10 folds instead.
```

Comment: How to make the key hold only the mean of those 10 values for each C value ?

Comment: Just call `np.mean(your_scores)` like you did, and assign it to `my_dict[number_key]` (generic example)

Comment: I tried to implement what you said now I'm getting the same score for each of the c values. I'm adding the code to my question. Can you tell me which part I'm doing wrong?